# How to move to next screen on click of Read only text field iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, storyboard

I have a textfield that is readonly. I have another Search View Controller(VC) also. My aim is when the user clicks on readonly textfield it should open the searchVC. I tried attaching Push seque to SearchVC but it's not working. Tried same with a button and works seamlessly.

Pls suggest whats the approach for this.

Comment: Put a custom button on uitextfield. and give action to button.

Comment: kareem mahammed.. you mean a simple button on top of text filed and set visibility to false?

Comment: dont set visibility as false just put custom button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use gesture to your textfield

or

You can use custom button above the textfield. You have to show/hide the button on textfield disabled/enabled

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

if (textField.tag==1)
{

   //write alert view to check "click on  this text filed alert is appearing"

    return NO;
}
else if (textField.tag==2)
{
   //it's behave normal uitextfiled
    return YES;
}
}
```